# JavaScript: recursion inside anonymous promise resolver functions

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise

I have a function that return a promise. (foo in this example)

I try to call this function inside their resolve function that was declared as anonymous.

I have tried with **`this`** but this not work.

my code looks like this

```
var foo = function(boo) {
    /* .... */
    return deferred.promise;
};

var bar = 42;

foo(bar).then(function() {
    foo(bar--).then(this); //"this" don't work
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to call `foo` or the anonymous function?

Comment: foo inside anonymous function and then(anonymous) with this anonymous function. I try to retrieve anonymous function inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to name the anonymous function

```
foo(bar).then(function fn() {
    foo(bar--).then(fn);
});
```

You can also declare the function separately

```
function fn() {
    foo(bar--).then(fn);
}
foo(bar).then(fn);
```

Comment: Note this won't wait for anything async unless you `return`